# Self join in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, self-join

I am having trouble with a self join statement in Ruby on Rails.
Well, it is kind of complicated and irritating but what I want to get is:
5 jobs out of the `JobCompact` table that has the same foreign key `build_compact_id` and either the `language "ruby" or "rubinius"`

My query looks as follows:

```
JobCompact.all(   
:joins => "JOIN job_compacts AS jobs2 ON job_compacts.build_compact_id = jobs2.build_compact_id",   
:conditions => ["job_compacts.language = ? AND jobs2.language=?", 'ruby', 'rubinius'],  
:limit => 5)
```

In general that seems to be working but only return me objects out of the first table. The second table (jobs2) is not shown in the result set. I would like to get a collection with all job_compacts that match the given condition.

I hope I could explain my problem, otherwise do not hesitate to ask me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide SQL describe statements for the tables involved.  First thing to look at is what foreign keys you have defined.  You can go into the mySQL console or you can type `rails db` to get into it (a little known trick that will get you into the console for whatever db you have defined in config/database.yml)

Comment: One thing to note is that you don't put the JOIN word in the statement.  Ideally you don't use raw sql either, just give the name of the table that is connected through an appropriately named foreign key.  This is what rails is all about.  Convention over configuration.